# Sum of distinct values after grouping explodes a metric

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using

```
with t1 as 
(
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date), MONTH) as month,
    fullVisitorId,
    product.productSKU,
    product.v2ProductName,
    case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '2' then 1 else 0 end as pdp_visitor,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '2' then fullvisitorid else null end) AS views_pdp,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '3' then fullvisitorid else null end) AS add_cart,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '6' then hits.transaction.transactionid else null end) AS conversions,
    count(distinct(hits.transaction.transactionId)) as transaction_id_cnt,
FROM `table` AS nr, 
    UNNEST(hits) hits,
    UNNEST(product) product
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
)
select 
    month,
    sum(views_pdp) as pdp 
    ,sum(add_cart) as add_cart
    ,sum(conversions) as conversions
    ,sum(transaction_id_cnt)
from t1
group by 1
order by 1 desc;
```

Which returns

```
month       pdp     add_cart    conversions     f0_ 
2021-02-01  500     100         20              10  
2021-01-01  600     200         30              20
```

I know that `f0_` ( `count(distinct(hits.transaction.transactionId))` ) is bad here because of `product.productSKU` and `product.v2ProductName` grouping.
In general, when user makes an order with 3 items in his basket, I want to count this as one order, whereas now it is counted as 3.

This `count(distinct(hits.transaction.transactionId)) as transaction_id_cnt` results in the correct output if I comment out `product.productSKU` and `product.v2ProductName`.

Running this query:

```
with t1 as 
(
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date), MONTH) as month,
    fullVisitorId,
    -- product.productSKU, # commented out
    -- product.v2ProductName, # commented out
    case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '2' then 1 else 0 end as pdp_visitor,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '2' then fullvisitorid else null end) AS views_pdp,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '3' then fullvisitorid else null end) AS add_cart,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '6' then hits.transaction.transactionid else null end) AS conversions,
    count(distinct(hits.transaction.transactionId)) as transaction_id_cnt,
FROM `table` AS nr, 
    UNNEST(hits) hits,
    UNNEST(product) product
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
)
select 
    month,
    sum(views_pdp) as pdp 
    ,sum(add_cart) as add_cart
    ,sum(conversions) as conversions
    ,sum(transaction_id_cnt)
from t1
group by 1
order by 1 desc;
```

Returns what is expected, but now I don't have `productSKU` and `v2ProductName` which I need. I suspect that the problem is that each order is a new line in google big query and when I ask to to select it by product name and SKU, I count the uniques and then sum it.

How can I achieve the correct summation of `count(distinct(hits.transaction.transactionId))` without losing the grouping by  `product.productSKU` and `product.v2ProductName` which explodes this metric?

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I've re-asked the question with more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67306912/getting-sum-of-distinct-values-when-grouping-by-an-unnested-value-in-google-big/67307098#67307098)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the group by Query you could cherry pick them as array(so you don't group by them):

```sql
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT product.productSKU IGNORE NULLS) AS productSKU_list,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT product.v2ProductName IGNORE NULLS) AS productName_list,
```

**Update per your below comment:** If you want to use them in further group by just save them as string instead of array.

```sql
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT product.productSKU, ',') AS productSKU_list,
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT product.v2ProductName, ',') AS productName_list,
```

Comment: So how can I have both of these 2 values as a result if in the end I want to add both `productSKU_list` and `productName_list` as in my second SELECT? Now if I add them and it asks for a `GROUP BY` I get `Grouping by expressions of type ARRAY is not allowed`?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Please check updated answer.

Comment: Is it possible to have values of sku and names not aggregated but to be a single item?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Use the concat function to put them together, you may have to create a new question if you have doubts about how to use the CONCAT string function.