# Getting sum of distinct values when grouping by an unnested value in google big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am querying google big query table which has many rows but the ones I am interested in looks like this:

```
date             fullVisitorId       hits.product.productSKU     hits.product.v2ProductName     hits.transaction.transactionId

20210427        63546815            MM52AF                      panda                           149816182
20210427        65198162            KGSA5A                      giraffe                         321498182
```

I am trying to count the total transactions by counting distinct `hits.transaction.transactionId`.

```
with t1 as 
(
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date), MONTH) as month,
    fullVisitorId,
    product.productSKU as sku,
    product.v2ProductName as v2,
    case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '2' then 1 else 0 end as pdp_visitor,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '2' then fullvisitorid else null end) AS views_pdp,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '3' then fullvisitorid else null end) AS add_cart,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '6' then hits.transaction.transactionid else null end) AS conversions,
    count(distinct(hits.transaction.transactionId)) as transaction_id_cnt,
FROM `table` AS nr, 
    UNNEST(hits) hits,
    UNNEST(product) product
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
)
select 
    month,
    product.productSKU as sku,
    product.v2ProductName as v2,
    sum(views_pdp) as pdp 
    ,sum(add_cart) as add_cart
    ,sum(conversions) as conversions
    ,sum(transaction_id_cnt) as transactions
from t1
group by 1
order by 1 desc;
```

Which returns:

```
month               sku          v2      pdp            add_cart    conversions     transactions    
2021-04-01          AHBS         615     10146410       365569      46885           46640
2021-03-01          HERD         154     10074095       399483      58162           57811
```

But `transactions` is not correct, I get the correct output using this:

```
with t1 as 
(
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date), MONTH) as month,
    fullVisitorId,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT product.productSKU IGNORE NULLS) AS productSKU_list, -- changed this
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT product.v2ProductName IGNORE NULLS) AS productName_list, -- changed this
    case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '2' then 1 else 0 end as pdp_visitor,
    0 AS views_impressions,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '2' then fullvisitorid else null end) AS views_pdp,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '3' then fullvisitorid else null end) AS add_cart,
    0 AS add_shortlist,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '5' then fullvisitorid else null end) AS checkouts,
    count(case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '6' then hits.transaction.transactionid else null end) AS conversions,
    count(distinct(hits.transaction.transactionId)) as transaction_id_cnt,
FROM `table` AS nr, 
    UNNEST(hits) hits,
    UNNEST(product) product
GROUP BY 1,2,5
)
select 
    month,
    sum(views_pdp) as pdp 
    ,sum(add_cart) as add_cart
    ,sum(conversions) as conversions
    ,sum(transaction_id_cnt) as transactions
from t1
group by 1
order by 1 desc;
```

Which returns the correct `transactions`

```
month       pdp         add_cart     conversions      transactions  
2021-04-01  9978511     396333       46885            30917 
2021-03-01  15101718    568904       58162            23017
```

But using this :

```
...
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT product.productSKU IGNORE NULLS) AS productSKU_list, 
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT product.v2ProductName IGNORE NULLS) AS productName_list,
...
```

Does not allow me to group or select `productSKU_list` and `productName_list` in my second select statement.

I believe this is because if one order is made with multiple items in the basket there are multiple lines in google big query with the same `hits.transaction.transactionId`
I tried confirming this with:

```
select distinct(hits.transaction.transactionId), count(distinct hits.transaction.transactionId) as total
FROM `table` AS nr, 
    UNNEST(hits) hits,
    UNNEST(product) product
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '200101' AND '210428'  
GROUP BY 1
order by 2 desc
```

But I get:

```
transactionId   total   
ABSAD54         1   
515ABDG         1
```

So at this point, I am lost, as I am unsure why I get the correct answer if I use the second script or when I comment out this part from the first query.

```
 --product.productSKU,
 --product.v2ProductName,
```

Any tips on how google big query works is accepted.

My goal is to have the correct output of `transactions` which is achieved in the second script but still be able to group and have values of `product.productSKU` and `product.v2ProductName`.

Answer (score 0):

in your second query , you need to aggregate them again :

```
select 
    month,
    sum(views_pdp) as pdp 
    ,sum(add_cart) as add_cart
    ,sum(conversions) as conversions
    ,sum(transaction_id_cnt) as transactions
    ,ARRAY_AGG(productSKU_list)
    ,ARRAY_AGG(productName_list)
from t1
group by month
order by month desc;
```

Comment: Is it possible to have it in the structure like my first query returned? For SKUs and names to be a single item rather than to be aggregated?

Comment: if they are not part of grouping ( which is not what you want) , then no